# Javascript to remove trailing &nbsp;

Tags: javascript

I am getting a string which is nothing but innerHTML, and so it has instances of `&nbsp;`. I need to trim the string such that the trailing `&nbsp;` alone are removed.
Tried this:

> var text; 
>   text = txtInnerHTML.replace(/(`&nbsp;`)*/g,"");

This removes all instances of `&nbsp;` which is not desired.. Only the **trailing** `&nbsp;` instances may be which may be zero or more need to be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Try `txtInnerHTML.replace(/(&nbsp;)+$/g,"");`

Answer (score 3):

Use the end of string anchor

```
text.replace(/(&nbsp;)+$/, '');
```

I remembered which one is which by the mnemonic *carrots are more important than money(. Weird, but it worked for me when I was learning. It basically says `^` is the start anchor and `$` is the end anchor. Probably doesn't make much sense out of localizations that use $ for money value.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = txtInnerHTML.replace(/(&nbsp;)*$/,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txtInnerHTML.replace(/(&nbsp;|\s)$/,"");
```

> **$**
>   Matches the ending position of the string or the position just before a string-ending $newline. In line-based tools, it matches the ending position of any line.
>   [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Don't forget about simple space " ". Regular expression above removes   or " " in the end of string